# How to add ArgMax to the end of ONNX model?

Tags: onnx

I have [an ONNX model](https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/onnx/models/main/vision/classification/mnist/model/mnist-8.onnx) where I get the output as an 1xN array of probabilities. I want to add ArgMax to the end of the model so that I get the index instead.

I tried doing this using `onnx.helper` but was not able to find a good way to do it. I can create an ArgMax node using:

```
argmax = onnx.helper.make_node(
    'ArgMax',
    inputs=['inp'],
    outputs=['out'],
    axis=0,
    keepdims=0)
```

but how do I append this node to the end of the graph?

Comment: Check this https://towardsdatascience.com/merging-onnx-graphs-da088dbaf9b4

Answer (score 1):

I usually use the `onnx.compose.merge` operator. If you have an existing model `original_model` that has some named output, in this example `output_original_model` you can create a graph from your node and use compose to combine them.

```py
original_model = ...

argmax = onnx.helper.make_node(
    'ArgMax',
    inputs=['inp'],
    outputs=['out'],
    axis=0,
    keepdims=0)

graph = onnx.helper.make_graph(
    nodes=[
        argmax,
    ],
    name="argmaz",
    inputs=[
        onnx.helper.make_tensor_value_info(
            "inp", onnx.TensorProto.FLOAT, [None, None, input_size]
        )
    ],
    outputs=[
        onnx.helper.make_tensor_value_info(
            "out", onnx.TensorProto.FLOAT, [None, out_size]
        )
    ],
)

combined_model = onnx.compose.merge_models(
    onnx_original, graph, io_map=[("output_original_model", "inp")]
)
```